# App Engine silently fails on some requests

Tags: google-app-engine

Some requests silently fail in my **python** app, intermittently and unpredictably. The hallmarks of the failure are:

- Request returns a 200, so the client doesn't know there's a problem.
- Request does NOT successfully execute on the server.
- No logging statements are recorded for the request.

Below is an example from my logs of a bunch of requests which are each supposed to write an entity to the datastore. You can see for the lower, successful request, a blue 'i' is present, indicating that `info` level logs were recorded. When I examine the datastore, an entity was successfully written for this request.

However, for the failed request, you can see there is just a white box, and there are no logging statements present at all. While the server returned a 200, no entity was written to the datastore for this request.

[image: Log Viewer]

Has anyone encountered something like this before on App Engine? Any ideas on how to debug it? I've seen it in multiple different apps myself, but I've never been able to figure it out.

**EDIT**

To clarify, the main problem here is that *code doesn't execute*, as measured by the failure to write an entity. The spurious 200 and lack of logging is an associated symptom.

Comment: Is problem that the logs are missing, or that the entities are not written?

Comment: The problem is that the entities are not written. The lack of logs is a symptom (I think), one that make this especially hard to debug.

Comment: What framework do you use to log ?

Comment: This is a screenshot from the cloud developer's console: console.developers.google.com. The logging entries are created through python's `logging` module.

Comment: What's your app's default logging level, are you setting that?

Is there any way that you could be catching an exception and it fails to get to your eyes?

Comment: Given that there are no log statements at all in the line and you appear to unpack the arguments and log them as soon as you enter the handler, this starts to look like an infrastructure/platform issue. In that case, I'd advise you to open a [public issue tracker issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), with "Type-Production" as a tag, including your app's app id and a timeframe, and one of us friendly community support people will take a look and see if we can figure it out.

Comment: can you provide a code sample ? Java or Pythion ? Do you have any filters ?

Comment: @Nick: I am explicitly setting the logging level to allow all logging. Thanks for the advice on how to file the bug. You've got enough useful info in that comment that it would make a good answer...

Comment: How do the responses in your client look when these 200 responses return? Yu should send a meaningful response other than status code and see if you can at least use that in the meantime to figuring out why your request fails to execute your datastore code (or fails silently)

Answer (score 2):

From a comment originally, but seems to be the resolution path for this issue:

Given that there are no log statements at all in the line and you appear to unpack the arguments and log them as soon as you enter the handler, this starts to look like an infrastructure/platform issue.

In such a case, it's best to open a [public issue tracker issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), with "Type-Production" as a tag, including your app's app id and a timeframe, and as much information about your app and request handler involved as possible, and platform support will pick up the issue in the course of triage.

That said, it's worth examining the handler to make absolutely sure there's no way you could be exiting from the handler and sending a 200 without logging anything or seeing an exception. It all depends on what the code handling the request is capable of, what stack of libraries it's build upon, etc.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this with the simplest app possible to eliminate the "caught exception" possibility, and then report the bug. Thanks Nick.